# How to list schemas in postgres from rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-console

I would like to get a list of schemas in the current database from the rails console. Currently, I am executing raw sql to get the info via

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select schema_name from information_schema.schemata")
```

Is there a more correct way to retrieve this information from the rails console with ActiveRecord?

Comment: Just curious, why not just open `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: schema.rb does not contain a list of schemas. It only contains tables and columns.

Comment: you can use structure.sql, it has all the schema names

Comment: where is structure.sql located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL query you used is very correct. Information schema is part of SQL standard.

ActiveRecord does not have a ready method for this.

So it seems there is no better way.

Answer (score 7):

i have tried the following ,it works for me.

```
data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select * from information_schema.schemata')
data.each do |schema|
  puts schema['schema_name']
end
```

it returns the schema names.

Comment: The only difference between this answer and the question's query is that gets more stuff from the database (`*`) which it then discards.